# When is alternative hypothesis not true in r prop.test?

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I did this `prop.test(90,95,p=1e-34)` and got this:

`alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to`

and then this `prop.test(500,1000,p=0.5)` and got this:

`alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to`

Shouldn't the output be different? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Compare with `prop.test(90,95,p=1e-34,alternative="less")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output just tells you the alternative hypothesis. The alternative hypothesis is independent of the actual outcome of the test. If you want to find out, whether the null hypothesis can be rejected, have a look at the `p-value` of the test statistic.

In your first example, the `p-value` is `< 2.2e-16`, and therefore the null hypothesis is rejected.

In your second example, the `p-value` is exactly `1`, and therefore you have no evidence for the rejection of the null hypothesis.

Comment: Then they are just wasting lines. If I know how to use the prop.test then I should know what the alternative hypothesis means.